# Are both conditions necessary (optimal structure and overlapping subproblem) for dynamic programming approach?

Tags: algorithm, dynamic

Does every problem of DP posseses both property or any single property is sufficient ?
If both conditions are necessary, i can't see optimal substructure in knapsack problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need optimal structure, i.e., that the problem can be solved by solving smaller instances of the problem (sub-problems).  Then, if the sub-problems overlap, meaning that solving different sub-problems involves solving some of the *same* sub-sub-problems, then dynamic programming can help.  If there are no overlapping sub-problems then dynamic programming isn't necessary.

For unbounded knapsack with non-negative weights, let `best(m)` be the best sum <= m.  if `best(m) != 0`, then `best(m) = best(m-w[i]) + w[i]` for some weight `w[i]`.

`best(m-w[i])` is a sub-problem.  If you can solve all of these, then solving the `best(m)` is easy, so knapsack has optimal structure.

Furthermore, solving `best(m-w[i])` and `best(m-w[j])` will both require solving `best(m-w[i]-w[j])`, which is the same as `best(m-w[j]-w[i])` first, so knapsack has overlapping sub-problems.

Comment: Don't you think having optimal substructures is sufficient criteria for DP? After all DP is all about taking all possible combination. And if subproblem overlaps, memorization helps. What I think is Memorization is just a part of DP. Do you agree?

Comment: http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/23599/how-is-dynamic-programming-different-from-brute-force Check this link

Comment: 1) No.  if sub-problems don't overlap, then DP (and memoization) is unnecessary.  For example quicksort and mergesort exploit optimal structure, but have no need for DP.  2) memoization is one way to implement DP, but you can increase performance and reduce memory requirements by attacking the sub-problems in a beneficial order, like the longest-common-subsequence algorithm

Answer (score 0):

Knapsack has definite optimal substructure.

To consider all subsets of items, there can be two cases for every item: (1) the item is included in the optimal subset, (2) not included in the optimal set.
Therefore, the maximum value that can be obtained from `n` items is max of following two values.
1) Maximum value obtained by `n-1` items and `W` weight (excluding `n`th item).
2) Value of `n`th item plus maximum value obtained by `n-1` items and `W` minus weight of the `n`th item (including `n`th item).

If weight of `n`th item is greater than `W`, then the `n`th item cannot be included and case 1 is the only possibility.